# How do solve this error when running apache spark 2.3.0 on Kubernetes with a jar from a remote source

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

Following [the instructions here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#using-remote-dependencies) I have been trying to submit a spark job to minikube, using a remote URL:

`minikube start
bin/spark-submit --master k8s://https://192.168.99.100:8443 --deploy-mode cluster --name spark-pi --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --conf spark.executor.instances=1 --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=<default-spark-k8s-image-build> --conf spark.kubernetes.namespace=spark <https://remote-location-with-spark-example-jar>`

The pod fails and when I describe it I get the error **configmaps "spark-pi-ad386ea0f7e4333dbd2a0ad705e94d66-init-config" not found**:

  `Type     Reason                 Age   From               Message
  ----     ------                 ----  ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled              50s   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned spark-pi-ad386ea0f7e4333dbd2a0ad705e94d66-driver to minikube
  Warning  FailedMount            49s   kubelet, minikube  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "spark-init-properties" : **configmaps "spark-pi-ad386ea0f7e4333dbd2a0ad705e94d66-init-config" not found**
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  49s   kubelet, minikube  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "download-jars-volume"
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  49s   kubelet, minikube  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "download-files-volume"
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  49s   kubelet, minikube  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "default-token-4ghj8"
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  49s   kubelet, minikube  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "spark-init-properties"
  Normal   Pulled                 49s   kubelet, minikube  Container image "timg-spark/spark:latest" already present on machine
  Normal   Created                49s   kubelet, minikube  Created container
  Normal   Started                48s   kubelet, minikube  Started container
  Normal   Pulled                 43s   kubelet, minikube  Container image "timmeh/spark:latest" already present on machine
  Normal   Created                43s   kubelet, minikube  Created container
  Normal   Started                43s   kubelet, minikube  Started container`

However there is no mention in the docs of creating any configmaps, and because the name of the configmap isn't known until you run spark-submit, I can't create one in advance to get more information.

For now my plan is to work around by baking in jar files to the spark docker image, but if anyone knows more on why this is failing that'd be great!

Comment: That error is transient, it clears up 4 lines down- SuccessfulMountVolume for volume "spark-init-properties". The rest of the logs indicates that the container starts successfully. What happens next?

Comment: Ahh thank you loads don't know how I missed this